# Connecting a Razer Tiamat 7.1

Tags: audio, motherboard, sound-card, headset, surround-sound

I have a box with a AsRock z77 extreme4 motherboard. Just got a new headset, which is a Razer Tiamat 7.1. Both devices state they support 7.1 channel surround. There is however a mismatch between the 5 cables from my headset and the 5 audio ports on my motherboard.

Headset:

- Out
- Mic
- c/sub
- rear
- **side**

Motherboard:

- Out
- Mic
- c/sub
- rear
- **in**

Does this mean I cannot connect this headset to my box without getting new hardware? I tried connecting it with the 4 matching connections which results in bad sound. Since I don't know if this is a hardware problem or not, I'm not sure on how to fix this. The information out there on 7.1 surround support is somewhat contradictory at places :/

I'm running Kubuntu 13.04 x64 as OS.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least one more stereo output channel. Fortunately ALSA will allow you to [combine multiple sinks to create a single multi-channel device](http://alsa.opensrc.org/.asoundrc#Joining_devices_to_make_multichannel) so you don't have to go out and get a new 7.1 sound card.

Comment: Is the information on this that is understandable for someone that does not know the ALSA internals? :)

Comment: You don't need to know ALSA *internals*, you just need to understand how it enumerates/describes sound cards.

Comment: It's quite possible that the motherboard only supports 7.1 output through HDMI or Optical.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: ALSA doesn't require all the channels to be carried by a single sound card. You can create a 7.1 output from four 2.0 cards.

Comment: Right, sorry. I meant to respond to the fact that @JeroenDeDauw stated that both the headset and the motherboard support 7.1 audio.